# Object returned by index operation is temporary (substr)

Tags: rust

I need to create my own string type for easily porting NodeJS functionalities to Rust. I want to implement indexing with `Range` but I'm getting error at `fn index()`:

```
/// Scalar Value string type.
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
pub struct SvStr {
    m_chars: Vec<char>,
}

impl SvStr {
    pub fn slice(&self, mut from: i64, mut to: i64) -> SvStr {
        from = i64::max(0, from);
        from = i64::min(from, self.len());
        to = i64::max(0, to);
        to = i64::min(to, self.len());
        SvStr { m_chars: self.m_chars[(from as usize)..(to as usize)].to_vec() }
    }
}

impl Index<&dyn SvStrSliceIndex> for SvStr {
    type Output = SvStr;

    fn index(&self, index: &dyn SvStrSliceIndex) -> &Self::Output {
        // ERROR in following line!
        // cannot return reference to temporary value
        // returns a reference to data owned by the current function rustc E0515
        // lib.rs(89, 10): temporary value created here
        &self.slice(index.from_idx(), index.to_idx())
    }
}

pub trait SvStrSliceIndex {
    fn from_idx(&self) -> i64;
    fn to_idx(&self) -> i64;
}
```

I tried to move code from `SvStr`'s `fn slice()` to `std::ops::Index`'s `fn index()` and I still get the same error. Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to return a slice or a copy of the range? Because you are currently creating a copy, but then return a reference to that copy ... someone has to own it.

Comment: @Finomnis Correct, I want a copy. If I can't use `Index` for that, is it possible to have a method like `s.slice(0..10);`? It's forcing me to borrow the `Range`.

Comment: I was able to use a generic bound for this, but I'd still like to use brackets...

Comment: `Index` is meant for borrowing. I don't think it fits your usecase. Sure, you can just write any function that takes your slice index.